# How to parse multiple values like -v, -vv, -vvv in one argument in python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have a case when I need to add to my command arguments without values like:

```
# command -v or
# command -vv or
# command -vvv
```

And I need to validate if "-v" is between 1 and 3.
And if it is not raise an error message.

This is one of the arguments I am adding and it is optional.

I couldn't find any solution (like store_count or other action) to do this during adding argument like:

```
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbosity', action=<any action>, default=0, required=False)
```

I tried by creating my custom action like:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
class CustomAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self,
                 option_strings,
                 dest,
                 default=None,
                 required=False,
                 help=None):
        super(CustomAction, self).__init__(
            option_strings=option_strings,
            dest=dest,
            nargs=0,
            default=default,
            required=required,
            help=help)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        count = getattr(namespace, self.dest, None)
        if count is None:
            count = 0
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, count + 1)

parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbosity', action=CustomAction, default=0, required=False)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Tried to set validation if `"-v"` is between 1 and 3 in `__call__` function but the variable `values` is always empty list.

Variable `values` is counted correctly but it is set after exit from `__call__` function.

I can do this outside of the parser.add_argument() but I want to have it prettier and avoid messy code.

Do you know how I can achieve this?

**Edited:**
Maybe this will be more clear.
The command:

```
python.exe .\mparser.py -vvv
3
command -vvv
```

Code:

```
...
parser = CustomParser()
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbosity', action='count', default=0, required=False)
args = parser.parse_args()

### Validate and consruct verbosity option ###
if args.verbosity > 3:
    parser.error(f'verbose shoudl be between 1 and 3')

print(args.verbosity) # prints 3
commmand = ['command']
verbose_option = ''

if args.verbosity:
    verbose_option = '-' + 'v' * args.verbosity
    commmand.append(verbose_option)

### end ###

print(' '.join(commmand))
# call(' '.join(commmand))
```

Question: Is it possible to implement this section:

```
### Validate and consruct verbosity option ###
...
### end ###
```

inside `parser.add_argument()`?

Comment: Why are you looking at values?  That is where you find say "file.out" in "-o file.out".  To require at least one "-v" use `required=True`.  And in your `__call__` method if count is already 3 then you throw your exception.  No?

Comment: `values` is empty list because `nargs=0`, which is also necessay to chain.  `-v` can't both chain and take a optional value.

Comment: This is exactly what `action='count'` -- built into argparse upstream, no customization needed -- is meant for. It's unclear to me what stops you from using it.

Comment: Great Q.  Now, if only that question was being asked for `click`….  Anyone know if it has a count equivalent?

Comment: A custom subclass of 'count' could certainly check for a maximum value, but often tests like this are just as easily done after parsing.  That post-parsing checking could even be hidden in a utility function.

Comment: Another option is just accept the 'count' `-v`, and ignore/clip values that are too large.  So what if the user wants level 5 verbosity when only 3 are possible?  Give him the max without making a fuss.

Answer (score 3):

You're describing the basic usage of the action 'count', as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action).

```
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbosity', action='count')
```

Interactive demo:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> _action = parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbosity', action='count', default=0)
>>> parser.parse_args([])
Namespace(verbosity=0)
>>> parser.parse_args(["-v"])
Namespace(verbosity=1)
>>> parser.parse_args(["-vvv"])
Namespace(verbosity=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue:

```
class CustomAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self,
                 option_strings,
                 dest,
                 default=None,
                 required=False,
                 **kwargs):

        super().__init__(
            option_strings=option_strings,
            dest=dest, nargs=argparse.OPTIONAL,
            default=default,
            required=required, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None, **kwargs):
        if values is None:
            verbosity_level = 1
        else:
            verbosity_level = values.count('v') + 1
        if not 1 <= verbosity_level <= 3:
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, "verbosity level must be 1-3")

        setattr(namespace, self.dest, '-' + verbosity_level * 'v')
```